# Animating a contour plot in matplotlib using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, contour

I am trying to create an animation in matplotlib that updates three artists, including imshow, contour and text. Using FuncAnimation I am able to update the text and the image components, but have not been able to update the contour. Specifically, I tried this as my callback:

```
def updatefig(*args):
    text_component.set_text(newText())
    image_component.set_array(newArrayData())
    contour_component.set_array(newArrayData())
    return [text_component,image_component,contour_component]
```

This code doesn't raise an exception but neither does it update the contour lines. I wonder if this is just a matter my not knowing the right setter method of if there is more to it. Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Thanks,
Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn´t full understand your code (also because it is not complete) and I would like  rather to comment your question than answering it... (but I don't have enough reputation to be able to do it!)

Anyway... I think the problem might be related with the contour itself, which returns not an Artist, but a QuadContourSet instance! Do you think this might be the problem? I had something similar with the ArtistAnimation...

If this is the point, you have to "[punch the QuadContourSet until it behaves like an 
Artist](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Matplotlib-1-1-0-animation-vs-contour-plots-td18703.html)"... I could solve my problem with all the information in the link!

Good luck!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is very much an answer (and a good one) rather than a comment. Don't worry about posting it as an answer rather than a comment!

Comment: Agree with Joe, and hopefully by accepting I'll be helping your reputation. I apologize for the incompleteness of the code in the question -- I agree it wasn't enough to be replicable but this does seem to be the answer.