# Updating contours for matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to update my contour lines in an animation that doesn't require me to replot the figure each time.

Most responses to this question I've found advocate recalling `ax.contour`, but as my contours are superimposed on another image this is unbearably slow.

The only response I've found that looks close to answering the question answers it with a dead link: [Animating a contour plot in matplotlib using FuncAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337188/animating-a-contour-plot-in-matplotlib-using-funcanimation)

EDIT: [this](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Matplotlib-1-1-0-animation-vs-contour-plots-td18703.html) is probably the intended link.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap as lsc
import numpy

#fig = 0; ax = 0; im = 0; co = 0


image_data = numpy.random.random((100,50,50))
contour_data = numpy.random.random((100,50,50))

def init():
    global fig, ax, im, co
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    im = ax.imshow(image_data[0,:,:])
    co = ax.contour(contour_data[0,:,:])

def func(n):
    im.set_data(image_data[n,:,:])
    co.set_array(contour_data[n,:,:])

init()
ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=100)
plt.show()
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you've figured this out by now; unfortunately, it appears that you must re-declare the entire contour/contourf set of artists and remove the old instance at every timestep. Here's some info copied from [this link](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/update-an-existing-contour-plot-with-new-data-td23889.html):

> The set_array() method (I think) only impacts the colormapping
> information for contourf, and even then doesn't appear to update.
> What you need to do is make a new contour plot and remove the old one,
> especially if you need to change the underlying contoured data. This
> should be as easy as C.remove(), but for some reason, this doesn't
> exist (I'll go add it in a minute).  So instead, you need to do the
> following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

x = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.1) 
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x) 
f1 = np.sin(X) + np.sin(Y) 
f2 = np.cos(X) + np.cos(Y) 

plt.figure() 
C = plt.contourf(f1) 
plt.show() 
for coll in C.collections: 
    plt.gca().collections.remove(coll) 
C = plt.contourf(f2) 
plt.draw()
```

[This answer is probably what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386372/increase-the-speed-of-redrawing-contour-plot-in-matplotlib)