# I am trying to make a contour plot animation in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, jupyter

I have 16 contour plots with changing titles and I want to just create an animation from the 16 contour plots.

I first set up the images and the data below, but I am having little luck in the animation part.
I am trying to follow this example but I'm struggling:
[Increase the speed of redrawing contour plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386372/increase-the-speed-of-redrawing-contour-plot-in-matplotlib)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np
import time 
import pandas as pd 



title = pd.date_range('1968-1-1','1969-04-01', 
                  freq='MS').strftime("%b %Y").tolist()
    
    data = np.random.rand(16,30,40)
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(15,10)) #15, 25 
    for i,t,ax in zip(range(16),title, axes.ravel()):
        x = ax.contourf(data[i],levels = np.arange(-.6,.6,.03), extend='both')
        ax.set_title(t)
        ax.grid()
    cbaxes = fig.add_axes([1.02,.5,.05,.2]) # [left, bottom, width, height],
    cbar = fig.colorbar(x, cax = cbaxes, fraction=.02)
    cbar.set_label('cb', labelpad=15, y=.5, rotation=90)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

My attempt at the animation part:

```
levels = np.arange(-.6,.6,.03)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(15,10)) #15, 25

p = [ax.contour(data[0],levels=levels)]

def update(i):
    for tp in range(16):
        tp.remove()
    p[0] = ax.contour(data[i], levels) 
    t[1:] = t[0:-1]
    t[0] = time.time()
    timelabel.set_text("{:.3f} fps".format(-1./np.diff(t).mean()))  
    return p[0]

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=16, 
                                         interval=30, blit=True, repeat=True) ## increasing interval slows it down!
ani.save("test.mp4")
plt.show()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-d70067088c5b> in <module>
      3 fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(15,10)) #15, 25
      4 
----> 5 p = [ax.contour(data[0],levels=levels)]
      6 
      7 def update(i):

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'contour'
```

The error doesn't recognize contour or contourf... How do I make a movie/animation of the 16 contour plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an array with all subplots:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(15,10)) #15, 25
```

You have to index the `ax` array to plot on the subfigures:

```py
# plot on the upper left subfigure
ax[0,0].contour(data[0],levels=levels)
```